# IE8: :after, position:absolute image not showing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am designing a website which has css menus.

Some of the menus have submenus.  Any menu item with a submenu shows a simple image of ">", to indicate that there are submenus.

[Here is a JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4XTa/). (Please excuse the 60 lines of CSS. I am working from generated code and I stripped out as much extraneous code as I could.)

This is not working in IE8 and I have no idea why. In IE8, the > image simply doesn't appear.

Can anyone help me make it so this code will work in IE8?

Using a background image isn't an ideal solution, because the page is already using a background image for another purpose.

Thank you!

```
.has_children:after
{
    content:url('http://s21.postimg.org/banv5jdib/submenu_arrow.png');
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make `:before`, `:after` and `content` work in IE8 you need to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the top of the page.

If still it fails, than you will have to use [CSS3](http://css3pie.com/documentation/) pie with [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/)

[For Support Details](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) Or [Here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after)

And as you told that you cannot use `background-image` than using `img` tag seems fair and only way to achieve this.

Comment: yes i knew it actually the ppl who r new dont know how it was pain in butt making ie6,7 and 8 behave

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "using img tag".  Could you briefly expand?

Comment: @JoshuaD By using an `img` tag to render the image on the menu